# Videos from the Guardian website not loading (Chrome)

Tags: video, google-chrome

I was trying to load [this video](http://www.theguardian.com/news/video/2014/apr/30/bitcoin-made-simple-video-animation) from the Guardian website but it doesn't seem to work. Other videos on the site don't seem to work either.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit) and have flash (13,0,0,206) installed and working correctly on other sites, it's just the Guardian media player that doesn't seem to work.

At first I thought it was because I am using adblock, but even if I disable it the video still fails to load.

I am using Chrome 34.0.1847.132. The video works in my Firefox, which doesn't have adblock installed at all.

Comment: I cannot replicate this problem with my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64bit) and Chrome 34 (Flash 13.0.0.206).